# stl binary_search gives compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, vector, binary-search

ALL,
I have a code like this:

```
bool ISearchable::PerformSearch(const vector<Passenger *> &passList, const string &lname, const string &fname)
{
    stable_sort( passList.begin(), passList.end(), ISortable( 7 ) );
    string stringToSearch = lname;
    stringToSearch += " ";
    stringToSearch += fname;
    binary_search( passList.begin(), passList.end(), stringToSearch );
}
```

The 'Passenger' vector is sorted by the same criteria, meaning, last_name + " " + first_name.

However when I try to compile it it gives an error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
10.0\vc\include\algorithm(2978): error C2678: binary '<' : no operator
found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or
there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          could be 'built-in C++ operator<(Passenger *, Passenger *)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const
std::string, Passenger *const )'
1>          c:\users\igor\documents\visual studio
2010\projects\project.cpp(598) : see reference to function
template instantiation 'bool
std::binary_search<std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,std::string>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const
_Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<Passenger
*,std::allocator<Passenger *>>,
1>
_FwdIt=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<Passenger
*,std::allocator<Passenger *>>>,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>
```

What is the error about and how do I fix it?
I saw the same code here but it didn't have any issues.

The Passenger class does not overload operator< as it does not make much sense. However it does consist of some fields besides last_name and first_name.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You are trying to search a vector of `Passenger *` for a `std::string` - the compiler does not know how to do that. It would help us if you could provide a [complete example](http://sscce.org), and a description of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Is there a conversion from `std::string` to `Passenger`? If so, apply this conversion to `stringToSearch` before passing it to binary_search.

Comment: Compiler is telling that it doesn't know how to compare a `Passenger*` with `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom comparator to compare passenger pointers to strings, something like:

```
binary_search( passList.begin(), passList.end(), stringToSearch,
    [](Passenger * p, string const & name) {return p->name() < name;} );
```

where you might need to change `p->name()` to whatever method `Passenger` provides to extract the full name.

If your compiler doesn't support lambdas, then you'll need to define it separately:

```
// In C++03, this must be at namespace scope for some reason.
struct ComparePassengerName {
    bool operator()(Passenger * p, string const & name) {
        return p->name() < name;
    }
};

binary_search( passList.begin(), passList.end(), stringToSearch,
               ComparePassengerName());
```

Comment: This is almost right, except the Passenger class here has only last_name and first_name fields, not name(), so they'd have to do: `return p->last_name + " " + p->first_name < name`.

Comment: @DerrickCoetzee: Indeed, my example assumes that the class provides a particular way of getting the full name. It will need modifying to match the actual interface.